# CSS in Internet Explorer: list-style-image and float:left issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have an issue with list-style-image property in CSS with Internet Explorer 8

If I set

```
li {
 float:left;
 list-style-image: none;
}
```

each menu item is above each other. If I remove list-style-image:none, they are perfectly positioned instead, but they have the dot image. (see images)

[image]
[image]

Comment: This question feels very familiar...what Doctype are you using? Also, incidentally, if you're trying to remove the bullets from the list you might want to try `list-style-type: none` instead.

Comment: hey, not really.. the bullets are still there if I use list-style-type. THis is the link: http://109.72.95.174/astudio/sites/danydiop/?q=taxonomy/term/26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the list collapse since you set `float:left` to `<li/>` and to the inner `<a/>`. There is no need to; removing `float:left` from `<a/>` solves the problem.

As for the list bullets, like said before, `list-style-type:none` is the way to go.

Especially for IE8, I also suggest to remove the `line-height:0` in `#block-menu-primary-links`. It may cause the collapsing behavior.

Note: I don't really understand the suggestion by @orokusaki. Tried without `position:relative;`, and it works perfectly well.

Comment: hey, indeed position:relative doesn't help at all. But the point is that it still doesn't work in IE. Try to give a look, I modified what you suggested but still the menu collapses.

Comment: @Patrick: you have forgotten to remove `line-height:0` in `#block-menu-primary-links`. Since each element has its height set to 0 pixels, it doesn't take any place, so doesn't move the next elements to the right. I agree that it's not something logical, but that's why normal browsers do not have this problem.